# Bash substring bad substitution in jenkins shell

Tags: jenkins

I need to do a substring.

```
str="Some random string"
str=\${str:2:9}
```

But this returns a bad substitution error. I've also tried

```
str=\${str%???}
```

But it still returns a bad substitution error.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Is the "\" in "\$" a typo?

Comment: @samabcde no. It is needed because if its not there it will interpret it as a groovy variable.

Comment: I don't get it. The writing without the "\" should work in a "Execute shell" build step. How can it interpret it as a groovy variable if you are running it in a Jenkins shell ? Can you provide more of your job configuration ?